# Cannot access docker website by domain

Tags: docker, debian

I need help with configuring docker on Debian 9.
I installed docker and docker-compose successfully.

I can access my host by IP (ex. 172.18.0.7), but cannot access by domain name (sitename.loc). I see an error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" or "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN".

Commands
$ docker-compose up -d
$ docker ps
works fine.

I tried disable firewall, it didn't help.
What's wrong? iptables?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the IP and name to your hosts file, but the container IP can change everytime you start it, so a better approach is to map the ports to your host, and then add to the hosts file this mapping:

```
sitename.loc 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thanks. But i'm curious, why it doesn't work using inner docker's DNS manager? My friends have the same docker image but other systems (Ubuntu, Mac) and it works for them without changing in hosts file.
Why Docker networks feature doesn't work?